# Add cell click event handler to datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have three columns, first column is textbox, second column is checkbox, third column is textbox. I want to add a click event to the third column where if a user click on that cell, it will automatically checkmark and uncheckmark the second checkbox column of that row. I tried this but it's not working.

```
AddHandler datagridview1.MouseClick, AddressOf form1.datagridview1_MouseClick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to switch your Handle type on the subroutine to "Handles DataGridView1.CellClick". Example:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim tempView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    For Each cell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell In tempView.SelectedCells
        If cell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            Dim tempCheckBoxCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = tempView("column1", cell.RowIndex)
            tempCheckBoxCell.Value = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, quick note - you will need to adjust the cell type found in the for each loop to whatever type of cell you are using; in the example I had column2 set to a simple textbox type cell.

Comment: How would i go about unchecking the checkbox?

Comment: Add a condition where the tempCheckboxCell.value = true to check true if it is currently false, and false if true

Comment: let me know if that helps or if you need an example

Comment: I got it, reason it was firing twice was because Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick, needed to delete the handles part.

Comment: Ah you already had a handler/reference to the sub, good deal glad it's all working for ya :)

Comment: Btw, that might error out if you select a box that isn't a textbookcell, so you'll want to probably do some validation checks before the foreach loop.

Comment: yeah i changed it to DataGridViewCell instead of DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Comment: Even better! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CellClick event.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    With DataGridView1
        .Rows.Add({"John Smith", 1})
        .Rows.Add({"Jane Doe", 0})
    End With
    AddHandler DataGridView1.CellClick, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellClick
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    If Not TypeOf dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = CType(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

    cell.Value = Not CBool(cell.Value)
    dgv.EndEdit()
End Sub

End Class
```